# Call data from database to be put as a title

Tags: php, mysql, database, fpdf

I am doing my homework with php and fpdf. I wanted to call a certain data from my database and display it beside my title. I am still learning and can't find any helpful tutorials that will give me ideas on what to do. I hope you guys can help me.

```
<?php

mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

mysqli_select_db('storm');

$sql="SELECT * FROM twothree ORDER BY ssh DESC";

$records=mysql_query($sql);

require("library/fpdf.php");

class PDF extends FPDF{
function Header(){
    $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $this->cell(12);
    $this->Image('logo.png',40,12,17);

    $this->Ln(5);
}
function Footer(){

    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);
    $this->MultiCell(200,3,"\n - The public and the disaster risk reduction and management council concerned are advised to take appropriate actions and precautionary \nmeasures, and watch for the next storm surge information. \n- Inundation/flood depth due to storm surge will depend on the topography of the area(s). \n ",1,'L');

    $this->SetY(-15);
    $this->setFont('Arial','',8);
    $this->cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo()." / {pages}",0,0,'C');
}
}

$pdf = new PDF('p', 'mm', 'Legal');
$title = 'Storm Surge';
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,15);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->MultiCell(200,4,"   \nSTORM SURGE INFORMATION \nSTORM SURGE: WARNING #01 \nFOR: TYPHOON ROSITA (YUTU) \nISSUED AT 11AM, 29 October 2018 \n   ",1,'C', false);

$pdf->SetBorders(array('LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'TLR'));
$pdf->SetWidths(array(30, 30, 40, 50, 50));
$pdf->SetAligns(array('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'));

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);

$pdf->Row(array("SS Height",
            "Provinces",
            "Low Lying Coastal Areas in the Municipalities of:",
            "IMPACTS",
            "ADVICE/Actions to Take"), 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){

$pdf->Row(array($row['ssh'],
$row['provi'],
$row['muni'],
$row['impact'],
$row['advice']), 1);
}

$pdf->SetBorders(array('T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'));
$pdf->Row(array('','','','',''), 1, false, 1);


$pdf->OutPut();
?>
```

So I want it to output like the picture I have attached below. The Warning number will be called from the database same with the Typhoon Name and the time and date.

[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK4qJ.jpg)

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: I am still learning. Thank you for your comment. @tadman

Comment: Being a beginner is fine. I'm just pointing this out so you learn modern best practices and not an unsupported interface. It looks like you're getting somewhere. Is the PDF writer you're using working for you? Remember to output the PDF data at the end so the browser can get it and render it unless you're intending to save this to a file, in which case you'll need to open a file for writing and write out the data.

Comment: To add dynamic values all you should have to do is [PHP string interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), like `"...Storm: $title"` where that variable can be pulled from anywhere, even a database.

Comment: I had an idea that it will be pulled that way but I don't really know how to code it properly. I've been trying and all I get is an error. The pdf is working perfectly fine. I hope you can help me.

Comment: When you get errors please try and be as specific as you can. Usually the best way to manage that is to show us the *exact* error you're getting: Copy-paste it here so we can see what's going on. That error may be trivial, or it may be complicated, but we have no way of knowing without seeing it.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: warning in C:\xampp\htdocs\HM\pdf.php on line 51

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file' in C:\xampp\htdocs\OJTTask\library\fpdf.php:404 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\HM\library\fpdf.php(1196): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\HM\library\fpdf.php(1132): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\HM\pdf.php(80): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\HM\library\fpdf.php on line 404

Comment: It's possible there's other code involved with that which is causing trouble, so is this a complete example or just part of your code?

Comment: I edited my post and put my complete code. Please check it out.